# How to 'cut out' DTM segment

Tags: dem, arcgis-pro

I want to cut out a segment of a DTM - to isolate a river catchment.
I would then perform hydrological analysis on the cut out segment - calculate flow direction and so on.
What is the best way to do this in ArcGIS Pro version?

- I assume I would need to convert the DTM to a shapefile, manually cut out the segment I need by hand, and clip it to the DTM. If so, I am concerned about data loss around the edges - would this likely cause errors in the analysis? *

Here is the DTM I am working with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is actually much easier.

You have 3 options, first one is:

Extract By mask (spatial analyst extension):
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm

Second (basic licence):
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm

Third one is a bit of a workaround (not recommended):
Convert clipping polygon to raster (Feature to raster)
then use raster calculator with command like:

```
Con(IsNull(Raster_from_polygon))==0,Original_raster)
```